# Apigee rest endpoint path mapping to custom path

Tags: apigee, apigee-baas, apigee127

I have rest end point /admn_resource_manager.I have created a apigee proxy to expose this.
I dont want to expose it like this to others as I want something like /adminmanager. 
Is there any way to map /adminmanager to /admn_resource_manager using Apigee.

end user would use http://someurl.apigee/adminmanager instead of http://someurl.apigee/admn_resource_manager

I explored KeyValueMapoperation and AssignMessage in Apigee.
I am not sure if these are the  right option to implement map path.I didn't get any example for this either.

Comment: Ok let me confirm your point, When user call your api by endpoint http://someurl.apigee/adminmanager and then you want to pass user to http://someurl.apigee/admn_resource_manager endpoint using apigee right?

Comment: @PimH sorry for late reply ....Yes you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

The way you would think to do this would be to use the Assign Message policy and use the Set -> Path element. But this policy isn't currently working as designed for rewriting the proxy's target URL. See the [Assign Message Guidance](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/policies/assign-message-policy#set-path) for more details.

To rewrite the incoming URL to a different target URL you can use the Assign Message Policy to set the entire URL (target.url) in the Target Endpoint flow, or you can use a JavaScript callout to set it. I chose to use a JavaScript callout because it gives a lot more control when rewriting the URL.

Here is an [example project](https://github.com/hoda9801/Apigee) on Github I put together for this you can use to see how I did it. It uses the swapi.co api as the target endpoint. This proxy uses the Assign Message and JavaScript callout policies to rewrite the URL. Here's some details about it...

**Proxy Endpoints**

- Create a proxy endpoint for each resource you are renaming.
- This is where you setup the Assign Message policy to set the variables for the new path suffix.

**Assign Message Policies**

- Set on the PreFlow of each proxy endpoint to set the targetPathSuffix and appendResourceIdToUrl (if needed) variables.

**JavaScript Policy**

- Calls out to the URLRewrite.js file to execute the js code.
- Set on the TargetEndpoints PreFlow and executes on each request
- Uses the variables set in the Assign Message Policies to change the target.url variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think Apigee can do it.

When I was started Apigee I have learned and try to understand from the picture below. (I think it is describe the main concept of this platform)

[image]

From your scenario,

- You can specify the URL that you wants client to call maybe *someurl.apigee/adminmanager*  or something else
- Apigee is a middle also known as a Gateway. When you received the request from client, you can manage whatever you want. Of course, including pass your client to other URL like *someurl.apigee/admn_resource_manager* . (You just assigned new url to that request)

Because I'm not an expert as well so, you this link below can explain you more information.

Link:[Using Flow Variables](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/fundamentals/introduction-flow-variables)